# equivalent to CopyTo() for CvMat*

Tags: c++, opencv

as OpenCv documentation mentioned , `Mat::copyTo()`is using an input of type Mat. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#mat-copyto

I need an equivalent function that takes an input of type `CvMat*` .

Answer (score 1):

[`cvCopy()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#copy) is the equivalent function in the C API.